# No image upload capability in UI with CKEditor gem, Paperclip Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, paperclip

I'm using the ckeditor gem (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), and paperclip gem, and CKEditor works, but I have no option to upload an image when I click the image button, only enter a URL.  I can't find any documentation that explains how to do this with Paperclip *and* Rails 4.

Comment: That documents is so pool, I've searched for hours but nothing get.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/297) that describes the problem:.

A solution is to copy the content of the config.js from [there](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js).

Comment: That solved it for me, after several hours of pulling my hair out. A custom config.js must include the original content. Logical when one thinks it through, but clearly not obvious.

Comment: Offical doc too pool to read!    waste my time. this works for me ,thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just modify config. solution from @KrauseFx

```
    /*
     Copyright (c) 2003-2011, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
     For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
     */

    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
    {
        // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
        // config.language = 'fr';
        // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

        /* Filebrowser routes */
        // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
        config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

        // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
        config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

        // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
        config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

        // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
        config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

        // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
        config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

        // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
        config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

        // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
        config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

        config.allowedContent = true;

        // Rails CSRF token
        config.filebrowserParams = function(){
            var csrf_token, csrf_param, meta,
                metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
                params = new Object();

            for ( var i = 0 ; i < metas.length ; i++ ){
                meta = metas[i];

                switch(meta.name) {
                    case "csrf-token":
                        csrf_token = meta.content;
                        break;
                    case "csrf-param":
                        csrf_param = meta.content;
                        break;
                    default:
                        continue;
                }
            }

            if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
                params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
            }

            return params;
        };

        config.addQueryString = function( url, params ){
            var queryString = [];

            if ( !params ) {
                return url;
            } else {
                for ( var i in params )
                    queryString.push( i + "=" + encodeURIComponent( params[ i ] ) );
            }

            return url + ( ( url.indexOf( "?" ) != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join( "&" );
        };

        // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
        CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
            // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
            var dialogName = ev.data.name;
            var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
            var content, upload;

            if (CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash'], dialogName) > -1) {
                content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
                upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

                if (upload && upload.filebrowser && upload.filebrowser['params'] === undefined) {
                    upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
                    upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
                }
            }
        });

        // Toolbar groups configuration.
        config.toolbar = [
            { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source'] },
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
            // { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
            // { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
            { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
            '/',
            { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
            { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] }
        ];

        config.toolbar_mini = [
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
            { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
            { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] }
        ];
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use ckeditor for image uploading as well, but I actually switched to the [rich editor](https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich), which is built on CKEditor, but handles image uploads better. I'm using it with Carrierwave and Rails 4, but rich is compatible with Paperclip as well (it actually added Carrierwave support later).

Answer (score 0):

You can give `ckeditor-imgur` gem a try, it will save your image to imgur for free and easy way to upload your images.

https://github.com/yfxie/ckeditor-imgur